# TIFF images: How 16bits-RGBA image pixels are interlaced?

Tags: c, image, libtiff

I'm trying to deal with 16-bits per channel RGBA TIFF images through C language, I could not find a lot of information about 16-bits images in the specifications.

In case of a 8-bits per channel RGBA image, I understand that a pixel is stored as a uint32, and can be deinterlaced by grouping the 32 bits into 4 groups (R,G,B,A) of 8 bits.
Then to deal with 8-bits per channel RGBA images, I'm doing the following (see also enclosed source code [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7BjiesaKCZ0U0ttT0F6WFVnMFU/edit?usp=sharing)):

1. I store the image data as a uint32 tab (using TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented) that I call `data_tiff`
2. I deinterlace pixels using the following commands: `(uint8) TIFFGetR(*data_tiff)`, `(uint8) TIFFGetG(*data_tiff)`, `(uint8) TIFFGetB(*data_tiff)` & `(uint8) TIFFGetA(*data_tiff)`

In case of a 16 bits per channel RGBA image, could you tell me how can I deinterlace pixels?
if I could retreive image data as a uint64 tab, then I could do the following:

```
#define    TIFF16GetR(abgr)    ((abgr) & 0xffff)
#define    TIFF16GetG(abgr)    (((abgr) >> 16) & 0xffff)
#define    TIFF16GetB(abgr)    (((abgr) >> 32) & 0xffff)
#define    TIFF16GetA(abgr)    (((abgr) >> 48) & 0xffff)`
```

1. I read the image data as a uint64 tab
2. I deinterlace pixels using `(uint16) TIFF16GetR(*data_tiff)`, `(uint16) TIFF16GetG(*data_tiff)`, `(uint16) TIFF16GetB(*data_tiff)` & `(uint16) TIFF16GetA(*data_tiff)`

but it seems that data are not natively stored in a uint64 tab, so I wonder how are interlaced 16-bits per channel images into a uint32 pixel tab.

I'm also facing difficulties dealing with 16-bits grayscaled images in the same way (using `TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented` to get image data and trying to convert each pixel into a uint16)

More generally, do you have any piece of documentation about 16 bits grayscale and color images?

Thank you,
Best Regards,

Rémy A.

Comment: What do you mean by the word "tab", above? I can't parse that ... Should it be "table", maybe?

Comment: I mean a pointer: uint32*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the `TIFFReadRGBAImage` high-level interface  will always read the image with a precision of 8 bit per sample.

In order to read a 16bit per channel image without loosing the precision, you could use `TIFFReadScanline` directly and read the correct amount of data according to `SamplesPerPixel` and `BitsPerSample`. But this would only work if the image is stored in strips (not tiles which has been introduced in TIFF 6.0) and there must be only one row in each compressed strip (if the image is compressed).

If you want to handle *all* kind of TIFF image wihout using `TIFFReadRGBAImage` then you have to detect the image format and use low-level interface such as  `TIFFReadEncodedStrip` and `TIFFReadEncodedTile`.

Note that the TIFF specifications are very extensive and flexible and using those low-level interfaces to handle every possible kind of image won't be an easy task so you may be better off using a higher level library than libtiff if you can.

**EDIT**

What you are referring to in the comment is the first part of the TIFF 6.0 specification known as **Baseline TIFF**

> « When TIFF was introduced, its extensibility provoked compatibility
>   problems. The flexibility in encoding gave rise to the joke that TIFF
>   stands for Thousands of Incompatible File Formats.[9] To avoid these
>   problems, every TIFF reader was required to read Baseline TIFF. The
>   Baseline TIFF does not include layers, or compression with JPEG or
>   LZW. The Baseline TIFF is formally known as TIFF 6.0, Part 1: Baseline
>   TIFF » from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Part_1%3a_Baseline_TIFF)

A Baseline TIFF does not support bit depth higher that 8 bit, so that's why in the specification of the Baseline TIFF, the value of `BitsPerSample` for a grayscale image can only be 4 or 8 and for a RGB image in can only be 8 bit per channel. Higher bit depth are supported as an extension to the Baseline TIFF specification and it is not *required* for a TIFF reader to support them.

Tiled Images is also an extension to the Baseline specification where `StripOffsets`, `StripByteCounts`, and `RowsPerStrip` fields is replaced by `TileWidth`, `TileLength`, `TileOffsets` and `TileByteCounts` so you can distinguish a tiled image from a stripped image by looking at the existing fields using `TIFFGetField()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I could read something as you suggest  somewhere on the web that also says that the major limitation of the scanline-oriented interface, other than the need to first identify an existing file as having a suitable organization, is that random access to individual scanlines can only be provided when data is not stored in a compressed format, or when the number of rows in a strip of image data is set to one (RowsPerStrip is one). which means that such a way to deal with 16 bits images won't work for any 16 bits image, do you know another way to do that?

Comment: Yes, i edited my answer to make the limitation of the scanline approach explicit.

Comment: ok thank you for this very complete answer. 
I would be happy to use an high level library but the less I introduce dependencies, the better it is...

Comment: I've been reading more about what you suggested, I have still few question: 

1. How can I know if the image is stored as strips or as tiles (I see no field dedicated to this question)
2. Do you know why it is written p.22 of the TIFF Spec 6.0 that in case of a grayscale Image, value for the BitsPerSample field should be 4 or 8 (and not 16, 32, ...) ?
3. Same question for RGB images, it is written p.24 that BitsPerSample field value should be (8,8,8) 
thank you again.

Comment: I see, thank you very much :) Indeed it is not an easy task to handle all kind of TIFF image, I think I'm going to restrict my code to Grayscale & RGB(A) images for 8, 16 and 32 bits per samples, it should be enough for most users. Next step will be to handle TIFF float. Anyway thank you a lot for your answers.

Comment: I have added an issue on gitlab now: https://gitlab.com/libtiff/libtiff/-/issues/420